# Xamarin Android - Picasso Out of Memory - Holding references to ImageView?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, xamarin.android, out-of-memory, picasso

I'm building an Android app using Xamarin, and using Picasso v2.5.2.1.
With a new Activity I've recently created, I've noticed that it gets OOM after a while.

I think I've narrowed it down after creating the simplest version possible. One Activity that loads an image into a small ImageView (the initial Activity did a lot more than this), and when you click the image in creates a new fullscreen Activity that displays the image.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Square.Picasso;

namespace PopDb_Android
{
    [Activity()]
    public class AdminItemImageActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
        {
            base.OnCreate( savedInstanceState );

            Window.RequestFeature( WindowFeatures.NoTitle );
            Window.AddFlags( WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen );

            SetContentView( Resource.Layout.AdminItemImage );

            ImageView ivItem = FindViewById<ImageView>( Resource.Id.ivItem );

            string imageUrl = Intent.Extras.GetString( "ImageUrl" );
            Picasso.With( this )
                .Load( imageUrl )
                .Fit()
                .CenterInside()
                .MemoryPolicy( MemoryPolicy.NoCache, MemoryPolicy.NoStore )
                .NetworkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.NoCache, NetworkPolicy.NoStore )
                .Into( ivItem );
        }
    }
}
```

The other Activity is pretty much the same - loads an image from a URL and displays with Picasso, then when you click on it, it loads the above Activity. I disabled the caching in Picasso just to make sure this wasn't the problem.

Other questions I've seen about this often related to loading too many images, or images that are too big. However in this little example I'm only loading one small image (~104KB jpg, 300*400, so ~0.45MB when in memory?).

I've monitored the heap with Android Device Monitor, and noticed that if you go in/out of fullscreen view a bunch of times, the heap goes up a lot, but even after forcing a GC, it doesn't go back down. After dumping out the heap and looking at it in the Eclipse Memory Analyser, I see the biggest objects on the heap are the ImageViews, the number equals the amount of times I went in/out of fullscreen. So the app seems to be holding onto the references of these ImageViews for some reason.

[image: Heap Dump Image]

If I continue going in/out of the fullscreen Activity, eventually the image will stop displaying and then it'll crash with OOM somewhere.

I'm at a loss on where to go with this now. Am I just doing something stupid, or could it be something else?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have more than one images'

Comment: Not in this example, no. I've switch to Glide for now and things seem to be ok.

Comment: Ok Sounds good the problem is bitmap btw